# Sqlalchemy: Association object for 3 tables with many-to-many relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many, associations

I'm working on a project and I have 3 entities that need to be mapped together with many-to-many relationship.
let's say my tables are A, B and C. I want to be able to know which Bs and Cs are associated with A and the same thing for B (which As and Cs are associated) and the same thing for C.

I tried to implement this using Sqlalchemy and this how my code looks like:

```
class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'a'
    a_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    b_children = relationship("Association")
    c_children = relationship("Association")

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'b'
    b_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    a_children = relationship("Association")
    c_children = relationship("Association")

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'c'
    c_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    b_children = relationship("Association")
    c_children = relationship("Association")

class Association(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'associations'
    a_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('a.a_id'))
    b_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('b.b_id'))
    c_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('c.c_id'))
```

I know it shouldn't be this simple so I'm wondering if this is correct or not.. because I want for example to be able to do `a = A()` and `b = B()` and `a.b_childern.append(b)`

Comment: What do you expect `a.b_childern.append(b)` to do to the `associations` table? Add a row with `(a_id, b_id, NULL)`? Or some random `c_id`? What you might be looking for is three separate association tables linking together `(A, B)`, `(B, C)`, and `(A, C)`, instead of this triple association table kind of thing.

Comment: Yes `(a_id, b_id, NULL)` is fine.. If I do the three separate association tables is it possible to get all `b`s associated with `a` by just doing `a.b_children` (knowing that I already stored everything in the database).

Comment: Yes, that's the point. An important point to make is that, e.g. just because a `C` is associated with a `B`, and that `B` is associated with an `A`, that `C` is not considered associated with that `A` (unless you explicitly associated them).